# SQL Update Error with replace

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't see what is wrong with this SQL:

```
UPDATE Show
SET    EnterOnine = replace(EnterOnine, 'http://projects.example.co.uk', 'http://www.example.co.uk')
WHERE  EnterOnine LIKE '%http://projects.example.co.uk%'
```

I am getting this error when I enter this into PHPmyadmin:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Show SET EnterOnine = replace(EnterOnine, 'http://projects.example.co.uk' at line 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Show` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql, escape with back ticks.

```
UPDATE `Show` SET ...
```

Comment: Prefect thanks, I would of thought MYSQL would be able to give you a more meaningful error message for something like this. MYSQL gives the most unhelpful ever messages ever.